# Can someone explain this interface of frigidaire front load washing machine?

Tags: appliances, washing-machine

Can someone please explain this interface (the buttons, what do they do?) of front load washing machine from frigidaire?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried looking at http://www.retrevo.com/samples/Frigidaire-manuals.html ?

Comment: Havent been able to find my machine's manual on the net.

Comment: I see we're still heavy on the tech folks from stackoverflow.com -- only a developer would call the front of a washing machine an interface.  :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like from left to right:
Load size, extra rinse, soak, no tumble, Not a clue, Water Temp, Cycle length

Comment: The button on the right is the 'Activate Skynet' command. Don't push it under any circumstances.

Comment: I'd assume that the "1/2" button is for low loads? That would make the first button be the tumble speed.

Comment: @arjan.  1/2 is likely a 'half-load'.  I think you mean Spin speed (rpms maybe?)

Comment: Yes, I think the first button is spin speed (500 rpm when pressed; 800 rpm when depressed). And then the last button, labelled "1/2", is for small load sizes. But well, surely Hasan will have figured it out by now. I wouldn't even know the Dutch words, let alone the English terminology. ;-)